# UICollectionViewController not registering custom cell class created

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change the color of a cell. I have a file called `HomeController` where I layout the cell. I created a custom cell called `HomePostCell`. I registered the `HomePostCell` in `HomeController` and nothing happened. The cell colors are not changing. I have my code below for both files.

Controller:

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {
    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(HomePostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
import UIKit

class HomePostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let photoImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .blue
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(photoImageView)
        photoImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I want five blue cells to appear but they are not.

Comment: "Did not work" is not a useful description of your issue. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain exactly in what way the results were not as expected. And why are you using an image view just to set the cell's color?

Comment: I am using an imageView because i plan on having an Image display within the cell

Comment: Your edit wasn't very helpful. Do the cells appear at all? Don't use the image view for the color. Since the image view fills the cell, actually give it an image. The color is useless.

Comment: is CellForItem at method calling check by debugging

Answer (score -2):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell
cell.setupData()

return cell
}
```